# Sha1 in Google API in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, google-api

I'm a bit confused on generating SHA1 to access the Google cloud API. I have been developing an App which retrieve or display data after you login your google email, I've already used the clientID from the Google platform and paste it to my code but it doesn't work there's no error in my react mobile and I think the problem is the setup of my google API but I've already created one.
Most resources suggest to generate the `SHA1' by using the command below

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/App/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Yet I see the result which generate the `SHA1` but it's confusing me on how to used the generated `SHA1` to google API

should I add `SHA1` to google Platform console? how?

The comment/image below describes the solution to my project but I didn't understand at all
[image]

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ToastAndroid, Button, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  GoogleSigninButton,
  statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: '174................................9328.apps.googleusercontent.com', //sample
  offlineAccess: true, // if you want to access Google API on behalf 
});
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
   userGoogleInfo: {},
   loaded: false
}}
signIn = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("asdsad");
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    this.setState({
      userGoogleInfo: userInfo,
      loaded: true
    })
  console.log(this.state.userGoogleInfo);
  console.log("ok");
} catch (error) {
  if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
    console.log("e 1");
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
    console.log("e 2");
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
    console.log("e 3");
  } else {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log("errrorr");
  }}
};
render() {
  return (
    <View>
    <GoogleSigninButton
      style={{ width: 222, height: 48 }}
      size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
      color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
      onPress={this.signIn}
    />
    {this.state.loaded ?
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.name}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.email}</Text>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
          source={{ uri: this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.photo }}
        />

      </View>

      : <Text>Not SignedIn</Text>}


  </View>
);}}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps for add SHA1 key in your google cloud console

1. you need to login your google cloud console when you create project https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=1&project=<your_project_id>
2. Then select your project and choose Credentials left bar menu
3. Right side API key section and click on API key which you want to
   add SHA1 and add your SHA1 key which you generated from command
4. click on SAVE button below within dew minutes your app will work

Refer below attachment which show where you need to place SHA1 key in google cloud console project

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but what does the app bundle ID mean in package name? it is related to the app that I've created previously in react-native? where should I find it? or should I create dummy name?

Comment: @CarlJade It is your application package name, you can find it form build.gradle defaultConfig section key is applicationId